# Set JQuery variable equal to option selected

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble setting a jquery value equal to the selected option of a dropdown. Currently it is set to a radio button but needs to be a drop down now that i'm told.

This is what I have so far, but does not do the intended function

```
var acctType = $('name=acct_info option:selected').val();
```

and the options.

```
    <div class='selectList quarter'>
    <select>
        <option value='Check'>Check</option>
        <option value='Paypal'>Paypal</option>
        <option value='Wire'>Wire Transfer</option>
    </select>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ - Your selector isn't formed correctly

Comment: That helps, but it is specified for a radio button. I need it to work as a select box.

Comment: `for` attribute inside an `<option>` doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: I updated it, this is what it is set to now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#account_info').on('change',function(){
  var acctType = $('#account_info').val();
  alert(acctType);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class='selectList quarter'>
    <select id="account_info">
        <option value='Check' name='acct_info' id='acctInfoCheck' for='acctInfoCheck'>Check</option>
        <option value='Paypal' name='acct_info' id='acctInfoPaypal' for='acctInfoPaypal'>Paypal</option>
        <option value='Wire' name='acct_info' id='acctInfoWire' for='acctInfoWire'>Wire Transfer</option>
    </select></div>
```